# MS Health API- Getting different userid when getting band data

Tags: microsoft-band

I will ask my question in a different way.

The below is the list of devices that the cloud api responds with.

1. What do these profiles mean?
2. I observed that the summary/activity data always comes along with the device profile where the deviceFamily and deviceStatus value is unknown. Can we safely assume that my application can tie the deviceId with the user who has authorized to collect data?
3. Is there any possibility that the data can come through for other device profiles?

   {
     "deviceProfiles": [
       {
         "id": "20BAAA7D-F6F8-458B-84C1-148D3BDDBCC9",
         "lastSuccessfulSync": "2016-05-03T18:32:43.568+00:00",
         "deviceFamily": "Unknown",
         "deviceStatus": "Unknown"
       },
       {
         "id": "0C8004BD-13D7-492B-91A9-BC2381F5496A",
         "lastSuccessfulSync": "2016-06-01T20:21:31.724+00:00",
         "deviceFamily": "IOS",
         "deviceStatus": "Unknown"
       },
       {
         "id": "FFFF1600-FFFF-FFFF-0130-454E19000E90",
         "displayName": "Katie's Band",
         "deviceFamily": "Band",
         "deviceStatus": "Unknown"
       }
     ],
     "itemCount": 3
   }